# Accessing ansible playbook task variables inside a callback plugin

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook

```
---
  - name: Test Playbook
    hosts: localhost
    vars:
      hostinfo_input: "{{ lookup('file','hostinfo.json') | from_json }}"

    tasks:
    - name: Check Server
      command: python3 check.py {{item}}
      register: async_out
      async: 100
      poll: 0
      with_items: "{{hostinfo_input.hosts}}"
```

I am using callback plugin to print something at the start and end of "Check Server" task. I have the following questions.

1. How do I access the {{item}} variable inside the callback function ?
2. Which callback functions can I use to print something at the start of the task and then at the end of the task ?

For start of task, I guess, I can use def v2_playbook_on_task_start(self, task, is_conditional): , right ?